# C# serializing/deserializing with memory stream System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to serialize/de-serialize a stream of around 50MB xml data with the following code and I get System.OutOfMemoryException exception.

```
   var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (stream)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T) formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
```

I debugged the code and it throws OutOfMemoryException exception on the formatter.Serialize(stream,source) line.

I did some search in it says that limit is 2GB. How can I debug to find out the reason or is there any efficent way of writing this code? Or any tool to watch the memory usage.

Thanks,

Comment: What type is `source`? Did you get a stack trace that details exactly where the out of memory occurred? (It might help to setup Microsoft's symbol server with this last one, in case it isn't showing you)

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you using `BinaryFormatter` to serialize xml? That ... doesn't sound efficient.  That is serialization data wrapped in more serialization data - both of them inefficient. In other news: don't use `BinaryFormatter`. Ever ;p

Comment: This is an old code written by someone and just faced with the issue when the file size gets larger. so now time to upgrade it to get it work. if you have a suggestion to make it better please share it below :) Thanks

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the xml file gets saved into database.

Comment: @akdurmus that doesn't make it any better... storing a massive blob in a database is *not* a good thing

Comment: @akdurmus That makes using BinaryFormatter even worse!!!! BinaryFormatter is intended for IPC communication on the same machine only. **Not for persisting data!** If any assemblies in the object graph get thier `AssemblyVersion` changed (Which happens all the time when you do windows updates) you will not be able to deserialize your data.

Comment: When you say large data? Are we talking about GB or MB? The max xml size goes up to 100 MB. is it considered as big blob?

Comment: Thanks @Scott. As I mentioned that the code is written by someone. I am trying to enhance the system. I don't have much experience with stream. Is there any good source that you could recommend? Or better a code would do the job :)

Comment: @akdurmus you have not given us enough information explaining what the process you are doing actually is for us to suggest alternatives. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29150269/edit) and add more information explaining the process of where you are getting the data from, what you are doing with that data, and where it is going to.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with 2GB of xml is **never** going to be efficient. However, to make it *work*, you could try writing to a `FileStream` instead of a `MemoryStream`, since a `MemoryStream` has a 2GB limit. Alternatively, you could write your own `Stream` implementation using multiple buffers rather than a single large buffer.

However, I **strongly** suggest that what you *actually* want to do here is some combination of:

- use a different serialization format (xml is a poor choice for large data)
- don't require it all in one blob
- have less data